# How to solve:"Unable to find node on an unmounted component." on entering text

Tags: reactjs, botframework

I have integrated Botframework V3 in my React website, incorporate a custom build of the Web Chat component.I have include cdn for style

`<link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

When ever i enter a value in my input tag,i get this error.

**WebChat.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Chat } from 'botframework-webchat';


export default class extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Chat 
            directLine={{ secret: ' SECRET_KEY' }} 
            user={{ id: 'user_id', name: 'user_name' }}/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Error

> Unable to find node on an unmounted component. invariant
>   node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:57
>   findCurrentFiberUsingSlowPath
>   node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4438
>   findCurrentHostFiber
>   node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4450
>   findHostInstance
>   node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18562 findDOMNode
>   node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19068
>   Chat.handleKeyDownCapture /home/React/Botframework
>   webchat/BotFramework-WebChat-3/built/Chat.js:160

Comment: Why do you use ```Fragment``` instead of returning ```Chat``` directly?

Comment: Well i will add more code's for a chatbot UI in my site.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the v3 "botchat" version of BotFramework-WebChat? Despite your bot using the v3 BotFramework SDK, you are not required to match the version for web chat. The v4 version is much richer, designed and built using React, and will integrate nicer. If you need example code, let me know. I'm running a v3 and a v4 bot in a React project. Happy to provide some sample code. (Note: The v3 version of WebChat is sunsetted and is to be deprecated.)

Comment: Are you using the same version of React in the webchat build as you are in your website?

Comment: Downgrading the react version to react: 16.5.2 solved the problem @EricDahlvang

Comment: @StevenKanberg I'm looking into v-3 for an old project build using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading the react version to react: 16.5.2 solved the problem